# Why is the position of assignment causing an infinite loop in this case?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, variable-assignment, infinite-loop

Could someone please clear up why the position of the following assignment is causing an infinite loop?

I am writing a test program to experiment with pipes which uses this script which is run on 2 terminals, and a third terminal that simply echoes to pipe1 and pipe2. If I put **received="$input"** just after the IF condition then the result is an infinite loop on the two terminals. However if this assignment is placed at the end it works perfectly?

```
#!/bin/bash 

received="null"
while true; do
        read input < "$1" #this is either pipe1 or pipe2
        if [ "$input" != "$received" ]; then
                echo "$input"
                echo "$input" > "$2" #again, either pipe1 or pipe2
                received="$input"
        fi
done
```

In terminal 1 I run:

```
./r_w_test.sh pipe1 pipe2
```

And in terminal 2 I run:

```
./r_w_test.sh pipe2 pipe1
```

And then in the third terminal I would run:

```
echo "hi" > pipe1
```

etc etc..

Why do I get an infinite loop when the assignment is placed **here**:

```
...
if [ "$input" != "$received" ]; then
        received="$input"
        echo "$input"
        echo "$input" > "$2"
...
```

Comment: `while true` is an infinite loop. It will only stop when something inside the loop executes `break`. You have no `break` statement.

Comment: You should have an infinite loop in all cases because of that.

Comment: You also need spaces around `!=` in `if [ "$input" !="$received" ];`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: thanks for replying, that was actually a typo, i can confirm the actual code had spaces. Also I understand that while true is what creates an infinite loop but this is necessary for the pipes to be constantly reading. If i type "hi", I will get an infinite number of "hi". But if i just change the position of the mentioned assignment I only get one "hi" (which is what I want). Why is this?

Comment: I tested your script and it runs just fine; then tried to move that `received="$input"` higher, as you say, but nothing changes (of course). Double check your script for typos, I don't see any problem.